# How to make mininet with RYU SDN work properly with iperf traffic?

Tags: sdn, mininet, iperf, ryu

when I generate iperf UDP traffic on a linear topology with 6 switches in mininet which is connected to RYU controller, I am getting a lot of packet in messages. like same switch is sending packet in messages for that traffic more than one time. Why is this happening? and how to solve this problem?